# Why does $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8\dots$?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, geometric-progressions

**I apologize if this is a duplicate.**


I was taught how to prove that $\dfrac{\pi}{4}=1-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}\dots$, and one of the steps was to write the equality:
$$\int \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} \ dx = \int \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}\cdot(-1)^n \ dx = \int 1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8\dots \ dx$$
Why does $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8\dots$? I have no idea on how to proceed with this. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of geometric series?

Comment: Look up the geometric series and substitute $x \rightarrow -x^2$.

Comment: It's only true if $x$ is less than one in absolute value.

Comment: @JPi You could also Taylor expand the series about some other interval...

Comment: Sure, but either you expand around one and the right hand side doesn't converge or you expand around some other value and you get a different expansion from the one that's displayed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use this basic fact from geometric series:
$$
\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n.
$$
Make the substitution $-x^2$ for $x$ to obtain
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}.
$$

EDIT: to elucidate the first bit, suppose have the infinite series
$$
a+r\cdot a+r^2\cdot a+\ldots
$$
where $|r|<1$. Let $L$ be this sum, supposing it exists; $|r|<1$ is actually a necessary and sufficient condition. Then $L-a=r\cdot L$ by construction, so we have
$$
a=(1-r)L\implies L=\frac a{1-r}.
$$
In our case, we have $a=1$, $r=x$.

Comment: Actually, $r=-x^2$.

Comment: Ah, I was referring to the first sum, which the poster had asked about in a comment. But yes, that too.

Answer (score 1):

$$1=1(1-x)+x(1-x)+x^2(1-x)+...x^n(1-x).$$

Just substitute $-x^2$ in for $x$.

Alternatively, simply multiply both sides of your equation by $1+x^2$ to yield $1=1$, proving equality.

Answer (score 1):

A geometric series is of a series for $\dfrac{1}{1-r}$. The article in wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) shows the series for this:
$$\dfrac{1}{1-r}\mbox{ at $r=-x^2$ is }\sum^\infty_{k=0}(-x^2)^k=\sum^\infty_{k=0}(-1)^kx^{2k}$$
This gives you your required series, which converges iff $|x^2|<1$. Alternatively, you could Taylor expand about some point $a$ to get the series for $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ about $a$.